# Removing text between two characters if a certain substring is found (python)

Tags: python, for-loop, substring

I am not quite sure why this is happening. I am trying to remove everything between the commas, but it seems to be doing something weird.

```
import re
jsontext = '123,0test123,456,4test567,789'
for log in re.finditer('test', jsontext):
    print jsontext
    logstart = jsontext.rfind(",",0,log.start())
    logend = jsontext.find(",",log.start())
    jsontext = jsontext[:logstart] + jsontext[logend+1:]
    print logstart
    print logend
    print '\n'
    print jsontext
    print '\n---end---\n'
```

it is producing

```
123,0test123,456,4test567,789
3
12


123456,4test567,789

---end---

123456,4test567,789
15
-1


123456,4test567123456,4test567,789

---end---
```

which leaves with

```
123456,4test567123456,4test567,789
```

but I am expecting the end result of

```
123456789
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding the following:

```
import re
x = 0
jsontext = '123,0test123,456,4test567,789'
while x == 0:
    log = jsontext.find('test')
    if log <> -1:
        logstart = jsontext.rfind(",",0,log)
                logend = jsontext.find(",",log)
        jsontext = jsontext[:logstart] + jsontext[logend+10:]
    else:
        x = 1
print jsontext
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have fixed it but your problem is basically the fact that

`for log in re.finditer('test',jsontext)`

continues to use the original jsontext and not the new value for jsontext.

You can prove this by using this implementation:

```
import re
jsontext = '123,0test123,456,4test567,789'
for log in re.finditer('test', jsontext):
    log = re.finditer('test',jsontext).next()
    print jsontext
    print log.start()
    logstart = jsontext.rfind(",",0,log.start())
    logend = jsontext.find(",",log.start())
    jsontext = jsontext[:logstart] + jsontext[logend+1:]
    print logstart
    print logend
    print '\n'
    print jsontext
    print '\n---end---\n'
```

You need to do this in a while loop, not in a for loop.

Comment: Ahh I see. I tried a few things by adjusting the jsontext variable, but I couldn't get it to change the variable in re.finditer(). I wasn't aware of the re.finditer().next(). Thanks a lot!

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work. I understand we are trying to update the `log` variable, but I can't get it to work. Putting it where you put it produced an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "removelogs.py", line 5, in <module>
    log = re.finditer('"EventName": "Log",',jsontext).next()
StopIteration`. I then tried putting it after, but the file comes out incorrect still.